# How to animate UIview when UIVIew is hidden in sameView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uiview

I have a view in that I have dragged one more View and assigned it has

IBOutlet UIView ***popupIpadView**  which contains tableview textfield and other button.

What my requirement is, on loading, **popupIpadView** will be hidden initially. When I click on a button, this **PopupIpadview** will appear. But I want this view to appear in am animated transition like left to right or vice versa. How can I do this?

For example, I am using the code below, but nothing happens.

```
- (IBAction)showPopover:(UIButton *)sender
{
    popupiPhoneView.hidden = NO;
    popupiPhoneView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.5];        

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Hidden property, set the alpha value to 0 and the origin to the left side out of the visible screen, say -320 x and 0 y.

In your animation block, set alpha to one while passing appropriate transition style.
Initially set your view to

```
yourview.alpha = 0;
yourview.x = -320;
```

Then set it to appropriate coordinates in transition code.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:window cache:YES];

yourview.alpha = 1;
yourview.x = 320; // new coordinates
[UIView commitAnimations];
```